# Send multiple mutual independent $http calls using $q.all()

Tags: angularjs

I have multiple mutual independent `$http` calls that need to be made.

```
angular.forEach(carrierDetails, function(carrierDetail) {
    (function(carrierId) {
        CarrierService.getContact(carrierId).then(function(response) {
            scope.contact[carrierId.toString()] = response.data.carrierOwners;
        });
    })(carrierDetail.carrierId);
});
```

`$q.all()` is not working because, in `$q.all()`, any failed call will result in all calls failed. In my case, all calls are mutual independent. Each call response data will be pushed into `scope.contact[]`. How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Well, if you don't want to send the requests in that function, then don't, and move that code to the function that should send the requests. There is no such thing as "initializing a call".

Comment: @JBNizet Yup, I can definitely do that. I am just curious if there is a way to use `$q.all()` to do this.

Comment: Ah. That wasn't really clear from your question. J.C.'s answer provides the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `$q.all()` for this, just handle the failed calls with a catch on each call. Then resolve the promise.

```
var promises = [];

promises.push(doSomethingAsynchronous()
    .then(function (response) {
        return {response: response};
    })
    .catch(function (response) {
        return {failed: true, response: response};
    })
);

$q.all(promises).then(doSomething);
```

Now all promises are guaranteed to resolve and you can check which ones failed.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this. If it works, I will come back to mark this as the answer. Thanks again!